# How to know which route was selected?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

1. I have created a function in the bootstrap to do the routing.

   2. Once a route has been selected I would like to know which one it is.

Ideally I would like to be able to get that information in the bootstrap too, let's say I have a 1st function `_initRouting()` which decides of the routing and then later in the bootstrap a 2nd function `_whichRoute()` which would tell me which route was selected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From docs:

> If you need to determine which route
>   was matched, you can use the
>   getCurrentRouteName() method, which
>   will return the identifier used when
>   registering the route with the router.
>   If you want the actual route object,
>   you can use getCurrentRoute().

So in your bootstrap you will probably need to get the request object and use the above or use a controller plugin

Comment: I'm afraid I have to remove the accept. It looks like the route isn't selected until we leave the bootstrap. If I call getCurrentRoute() at the end of my boostrap I get a "Current route is not defined" exception. The question was about getting "that information in the bootstrap too". Any idea?

Comment: @user359650 There is no way to do that, i think. That is because the routing has not happened while in the bootstrap.